# NLP: Words and Polarity

Tags: nlp

Is anyone aware of any repository that has words and their polarities as score. 
Example

```
Word | Polarity
bad | -1
worst | -3 
better | 1 
best | 3
```

Thanks

A

Comment: Ankit, the latest works in the area usually claim that the direct assignment of polarity to words is not very effective. Most people suggest taking some context into account. Even in your example, how would you score the word "bad" in the following (not grammatically correct, but realistic) sentence: "Cool phone, I want it real bad!" For this reason, not much effort is spent on creating dictionaries like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a sentiment lexicon. A sentiment lexicon is a dictionary of words, in which each word has a corresponding sentiment score (ranging from very negative to very positive).  There are several sentiment lexicons that you could use, such as sentiwordnet, sentistrength, and AFINN just to name a few. The easiest to use among these is AFINN which I recommend you to start with. Later you can upgrade to a more suitable one based on your application. You can find information about AFINN [here](http://neuro.imm.dtu.dk/wiki/AFINN) and download it from [here](http://www2.compute.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/6010/zip/imm6010.zip). 
While Alex Nevidomsky is generally correct in his comment, in sentiment analysis problems there are many ways to circumvent such limitations, by learning the context of a word. Let me know if you had any further questions.